# What is a unit modulus?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What do we mean by saying that "an inner function has a unit modulus almost everywhere on the circle" what is the unit modulus?

Comment: Can you include some more context around this quote? Where is it from? I would guess it means the size is 1 in some norm or absolute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $|f(e^{it}|=1$ for almost every $t$.